# How to use ToFuture in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, eager-loading

Say I have these queries

```
// Linq 
    var allRecords = session.Query<Table1P>().FetchMany(x => x.Table2).FetchMany(x => x.Table3).FetchMany(x => x.Table4).FetchMany(x => x.Table6).ToList();

// Hql
string hqlQuery = @"from Table1 tbl1
                                left join fetch tbl1.Table2 tbl2
                                left join fetch tbl1.Table3
                                left join fetch tbl1.Table4
                                left join fetch tbl1.Table6
                                left join fetch tbl2.Table5s";
```

In the cases above I need to do all these joins to stop lazy loading and do eager loading. Now this would produce an alert in the nhibernate profiler about too many joins.

http://nhprof.com/Learn/Alerts/TooManyJoins

So one way to stop this alert is to break up the joins. and do multiple queries. This is what I am trying to do. However at the same time I been reading about the future feature that I think would allow me to break up the query(to stop too many joins) but still execute it in one go.

***Edit***

I been trying ToFuture and finding it slower when trying to limit the amount of data to come back(if I try to get everything back then it is faster as it does not crash).

```
  var allRecords = session.Query<Table1P>().FetchMany(x => x.Table2).FetchMany(x => x.Table3).FetchMany(x => x.Table4).FetchMany(x => x.Table6).Take(3000).ToList();

// result (2.731 seconds), row count 3000, duration 8 ms/ 2013 ms

select TOP (3000 /* @p0 */) table1p0_.Id        as Id1_0_,
                 table2x1_.Id        as Id2_1_,
                 table3x2_.Id        as Id3_2_,
                 table4x3_.Id        as Id4_3_,
                 table6x4_.Id        as Id6_4_,
                 table1p0_.F1        as F2_1_0_,
                 table1p0_.F2        as F3_1_0_,
                 table1p0_.F3        as F4_1_0_,
                 table2x1_.F1        as F2_2_1_,
                 table2x1_.F2        as F3_2_1_,
                 table2x1_.F3        as F4_2_1_,
                 table2x1_.Table1_id as Table5_2_1_,
                 table2x1_.Table1_id as Table5_0__,
                 table2x1_.Id        as Id0__,
                 table3x2_.F1        as F2_3_2_,
                 table3x2_.F2        as F3_3_2_,
                 table3x2_.F3        as F4_3_2_,
                 table3x2_.Table1_id as Table5_3_2_,
                 table3x2_.Table1_id as Table5_1__,
                 table3x2_.Id        as Id1__,
                 table4x3_.F1        as F2_4_3_,
                 table4x3_.F2        as F3_4_3_,
                 table4x3_.F3        as F4_4_3_,
                 table4x3_.Table1_id as Table5_4_3_,
                 table4x3_.Table1_id as Table5_2__,
                 table4x3_.Id        as Id2__,
                 table6x4_.F1        as F2_6_4_,
                 table6x4_.F2        as F3_6_4_,
                 table6x4_.F3        as F4_6_4_,
                 table6x4_.Table1_id as Table5_6_4_,
                 table6x4_.Table1_id as Table5_3__,
                 table6x4_.Id        as Id3__
from   Table1 table1p0_
       left outer join [Table2] table2x1_
         on table1p0_.Id = table2x1_.Table1_id
       left outer join [Table3] table3x2_
         on table1p0_.Id = table3x2_.Table1_id
       left outer join [Table4] table4x3_
         on table1p0_.Id = table4x3_.Table1_id
       left outer join [Table6] table6x4_
         on table1p0_.Id = table6x4_.Table1_id
```

Using ToFuture

```
// result (4.808 seconds), row count 6944 / 75/ 374, duration 1ms / 4022 ms

                // will load the Entities with Table2 fetched
                var allRecords = session.Query<Table1P>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.Table2)
                    .ToFuture()
                    .Take(3000);

                // will load the Entities with Table3 fetched
                session.Query<Table1P>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.Table3)
                    .ToFuture();

                // will load the Entities with Table4 fetched
                session.Query<Table1P>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.Table4)
                    .ToFuture();

                // will load the Entities with Table6 fetched
                session.Query<Table1P>()
                    .FetchMany(x => x.Table6)
                    .ToFuture();

                // will trigger all queries at once and the session cache will make sure,
                // that the results of all queries fill the same Entities
                allRecords.ToList();


select table1p0_.Id        as Id1_0_,
       table2x1_.Id        as Id2_1_,
       table1p0_.F1        as F2_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F2        as F3_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F3        as F4_1_0_,
       table2x1_.F1        as F2_2_1_,
       table2x1_.F2        as F3_2_1_,
       table2x1_.F3        as F4_2_1_,
       table2x1_.Table1_id as Table5_2_1_,
       table2x1_.Table1_id as Table5_0__,
       table2x1_.Id        as Id0__
from   Table1 table1p0_
       left outer join [Table2] table2x1_
         on table1p0_.Id = table2x1_.Table1_id;



select table1p0_.Id        as Id1_0_,
       table3x1_.Id        as Id3_1_,
       table1p0_.F1        as F2_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F2        as F3_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F3        as F4_1_0_,
       table3x1_.F1        as F2_3_1_,
       table3x1_.F2        as F3_3_1_,
       table3x1_.F3        as F4_3_1_,
       table3x1_.Table1_id as Table5_3_1_,
       table3x1_.Table1_id as Table5_0__,
       table3x1_.Id        as Id0__
from   Table1 table1p0_
       left outer join [Table3] table3x1_
         on table1p0_.Id = table3x1_.Table1_id;



select table1p0_.Id        as Id1_0_,
       table4x1_.Id        as Id4_1_,
       table1p0_.F1        as F2_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F2        as F3_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F3        as F4_1_0_,
       table4x1_.F1        as F2_4_1_,
       table4x1_.F2        as F3_4_1_,
       table4x1_.F3        as F4_4_1_,
       table4x1_.Table1_id as Table5_4_1_,
       table4x1_.Table1_id as Table5_0__,
       table4x1_.Id        as Id0__
from   Table1 table1p0_
       left outer join [Table4] table4x1_
         on table1p0_.Id = table4x1_.Table1_id;



select table1p0_.Id        as Id1_0_,
       table6x1_.Id        as Id6_1_,
       table1p0_.F1        as F2_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F2        as F3_1_0_,
       table1p0_.F3        as F4_1_0_,
       table6x1_.F1        as F2_6_1_,
       table6x1_.F2        as F3_6_1_,
       table6x1_.F3        as F4_6_1_,
       table6x1_.Table1_id as Table5_6_1_,
       table6x1_.Table1_id as Table5_0__,
       table6x1_.Id        as Id0__
from   Table1 table1p0_
       left outer join [Table6] table6x1_
         on table1p0_.Id = table6x1_.Table1_id;
```

Queries and times taken from nhibernate profiler. Test was run by running it once with one of the sets of code, recording the results, stopping the .net development server and then running the other set of code.

Table1 - 6200 rows
Table2 - 744 rows
Table3 - 75 rows
Table4 - 374 rows
Table6 - 300 rows

Pretty much Table 1 has a one to many to all the other tables.

Comment: Your `.Take(3000)` should come before `.ToFuture()` if you want it to be applied to the query as a `TOP(3000)`

Comment: Ah. Ok Now I get 3021/ 3998 / 374/ 300 for row count. Duration 35ms/ 4825 with a total of 5.703 seconds. With doing it all in one go I get 3000 rows with a duration of 2ms / 2307 ms with a total of 3.33. Seems like ToFuture() needs to return more rows to get the same amount and is slower. Not sure if that is just how it is or if I am still doing something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// will load the Entities with Table2 fetched
var allRecords = session.Query<Table1P>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.Table2)
    .ToFuture();

// will load the Entities with Table3 fetched
session.Query<Table1P>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.Table3)
    .ToFuture();

// will load the Entities with Table4 fetched
session.Query<Table1P>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.Table4)
    .ToFuture();

// will load the Entities with Table6 fetched
session.Query<Table1P>()
    .FetchMany(x => x.Table6)
    .ToFuture();

// will trigger all queries at once and the session cache will make sure,
// that the results of all queries fill the same Entities
allRecords.ToList();
```

change

```
       .ToFuture()
       .Take(3000);
```

to

```
       .Take(3000);
       .ToFuture()
```

Update:

```
// Hql
var allRecords = session.CreateQuery("from Table1 left join fetch tbl1.Table2")
    .ToFuture<Table1>();

...
```

Strange that this is slower than the big join. I can't test here right now. Maybe with not so many rows in the db the overhead for multiple resultsets is greater than that of extensiv joins. Can you try with more data in db?

Comment: I think, I tried something very similar( I will try again). What I noticed though was it was actually slower then just having it all in one go. I also found that it returned more rows breaking it apart versus all together(one reason why it might have been slower). Is this to be expected?

Comment: Hmm maybe it is not slower. I would have to try with a take on this future to compare(if I try to do it all in one go with no take, I get an out of memory exception). What do I do a take on in this one? All of the queries? The first one? Say I want 3000 rows back from Table1P do I just do a take on that and the rest will only grab back the ones from table 1? Also how do you do this query in hql?